# Regular expression to replace a file name in the full path to file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I have a batch file(.bat) whose contents looks something like below

> cd C:\RunningDir\TestResults vstest.console.exe
>   C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\BVTTests.orderedtest
>   /Settings:C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\QuestCodedUI.testsettings
>   /Logger:trx vstest.console.exe
>   C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\Functional_Tests_1.orderedtest
>   /Settings:C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\QuestCodedUI.testsettings
>   /Logger:trx vstest.console.exe
>   C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\EndToEndTests_Part5.orderedtest
>   /Settings:C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\QuestCodedUI.testsettings
>   /Logger:trx

Now I need to Find "BVTTests.orderedtest" and replace it with "SmokeTests.orderedtest" and replace "Functional_Tests_1" with "Functional_Tests_3" so that the file after replacement looks like

> cd C:\RunningDir\TestResults vstest.console.exe
>   C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\SmokeTests.orderedtest
>   /Settings:C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\QuestCodedUI.testsettings
>   /Logger:trx vstest.console.exe
>   C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\Functional_Tests_3.orderedtest
>   /Settings:C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\QuestCodedUI.testsettings
>   /Logger:trx vstest.console.exe
>   C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\EndToEndTests_Part5.orderedtest
>   /Settings:C:\Dir1\Dir2\ProductBin\TestBin\bin\Debug\QuestCodedUI.testsettings
>   /Logger:trx

I have written code something like below but it replaces all strings between .....\ with the replacement string. please help me with the right regular expression.

```
var batchReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\SystemSetup\Runner.bat"));
string linevalue = String.Empty;
string pattern = @"([^\/]*.)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string replacement = "SmokeTests.orderedtest";
while(!batchReader.EndOfStream)
{
    linevalue = batchReader.ReadLine();
    if(linevalue.Contains("vstest"))
    {
           string newone = rgx.Replace(linevalue, replacement);                         
    }

}
```

but output is SmokeTests.orderedtestSmokeTests.orderedtestSmokeTests.orderedtest

Comment: Why not simply do it like this with powershell: `powershell -Command "(gc C:\SystemSetup\Runner.bat) -replace 'BVTTests.orderedtest', 'SmokeTests.orderedtest' | Out-File C:\SystemSetup\Runner.bat"`

Comment: Thank you alex. as given below I want find a pattern \SomeName.orderedtest and replacethat with \someothername.orderedtest. I will have the someothername handy and it can have letters,numbers,orunderscore. As i parse each like I will replace existing ordered test with some other new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need a regular expression to do what you want:

```
var path = @"C:\SystemSetup\Runner.bat";
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
text = text.Replace("BVTTests.orderedtest", "SmokeTests.orderedtest");
text = text.Replace("Functional_Tests_1", "Functional_Tests_3");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Is there a specific reason you want to use Regex?

Edit:
You can find all occurences of your test files like so:

```
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\\)[^\\.]+?.orderedtest")
    .OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

And then somehow decide which of them you want to replace and with what

Comment: Unfortunately Its not always "BVTTests.orderedtest" or "Functional_Tests_1" and I would not know the name of the file in advance. Only think i know is that if a starting word is vstest then that like has orderedtest as part of it. So i thought using regular expression i can find a pattern such that replace only the part where it starts with \SomeName.orderedTest and replace the somename with the one I want. orderedtest file name can letters, numbers and underscore.

Comment: @VinayaPC and how do you know that you want to replace "Functional_Tests_3" and not "EndToEndTests_Part5"? What are the rules of the replacement? How do you generate new names of the tests?

Comment: Yes it did help and it provided me the regular expression pattern that i was looking for. Remaining things i knew how to handle...Thank you very much !